# IPython tab completes only some modules

Tags: python, module, ipython, tab-completion, enthought

I'm using the EPD version of python and IPython. After installing some modules using easy_install I notice that, although they can be imported, they cannot be tab completed. They exist on the path but, while included modules (pylab, readline, math) *can* be completed, these new modules cannot.

Anyone know what I should look into to find the problem? I've checked that the packages are in the same place as other modules:

```
In [1]: import pylab

In [2]: pylab
Out[2]: <module 'pylab' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/5.0.0/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pylab.pyc'>

In [3]: import BeautifulSoup

In [4]: BeautifulSoup
Out[4]: <module 'BeautifulSoup' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/5.0.0/lib/python2.5/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1-py2.5.egg/BeautifulSoup.pyc'>
```

Maybe something not handling the `.eggs` correctly? Thanks.

**Update**: Following up on gnibbler's post, I've found that the tab completion hits an exception at line 633 in completer.py at:

```
    try:
        ret = self.matches[state].replace(magic_prefix,magic_escape)
        return ret
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

But what is causing the failiure...

**Update**:

```
In [5]: from Bea<tab_here>
*** COMPLETE: <Bea> (0)
matches: []
state: 0
```

So this is just saying that the matches list is an empty set: there are no matches. It is still not finding the module. I'll try to investigate where `matches` is getting the modules its looking for when I have time.

Comment: Do you mean that import Be<tab> doesn't work? or BeautifulSoup.<tab> doesn't work?

Comment: The former. After typing out the name by hand and importing, tab completion kicks in for the members of the modules.

Comment: Same problem here, with Python 2.6.2 and IPython 0.10 on Mac OS X…

Comment: The IndexError would indicate that state is not in matches. Can you try printing them both in the exception handler?

Answer (score 13):

I found an answer to this question yesterday, after I got tired of this behavior.

It seems that IPython has a simple database with all the modules it can find in `sys.path`. Every time you install a new module you have to write the magic

```
In [1]: %rehashx
```

so that IPython regenerates its database. Then you can have TAB-completion of new modules.

Answer (score 2):

right at the end of Ipython/completer.py is this code:

```
        except:
            #from IPython.ultraTB import AutoFormattedTB; # dbg
            #tb=AutoFormattedTB('Verbose');tb() #dbg

            # If completion fails, don't annoy the user.
            return None
```

Perhaps uncommenting it will give you a clue

Comment: No luck. Nothing was "Verbose" about the lack of completion.

Answer (score 0):

Locally installed, *non-egg* modules can have their name tab-completed, when doing `import`, but *egg* modules cannot (IPython 0.10, Python 2.6.2, Mac OS X).

I would suggest to file a feature request / bug report with IPython!