# Python. View the "import" name of a library

Tags: python, pip

Some Python libraries are listed under one name in pip, but imported under a different name in the interpreter.

pycroptodome is a good example. In pip list, you see "pycryptodome". In a Python program, you have to call "import Crypto". "import pycryptodome" gives an error that the module doesn't exist.

Some libraries I've imported are giving me "module not found" errors. I want to see if they're imported under a different name from what appears in pip. Where can I find that data?

For reference, "pip show " and "pip inspect " don't seem to have this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get available modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952513/get-available-modules)

Comment: *"I want to see if they're imported under a different name"*, Best place to check is Package's documentation website - "installation" page in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get the import name:
Open the folder that your packages are installed ( Specified in `Location` in `pip show pycryptodome`). Then open the package `dist-info` folder (`pycryptodome-3.16.0.dist-info`). open `top_level.txt`. you can see the name you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

go https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome

download the tar file version you downloaded using pip and see the top-level view to see import names